# updating mysql table using variables from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db that stores medical bills data with the following variables:
dos, patient, original, pmts, outstanding.

After I make a payment, I want to be able to subtract the payment out from outstanding and add it to pmts.

```
$pmt = $_POST[pmt];
$patient = $_POST[patient];
$dos = $_POST[dos];

$sql=("UPDATE medical 
SET pmts = pmts + $pmt
WHERE dos = $dos AND patient = $patient");
```

the POST[] are coming from an HTML form.

It is not providing an error; however, it is not updating the existing table (medical).

Comment: Read up about (1) data sanitizing (protect yourself against sql-injection attacks) and read up about `mysql_query` (or better: `mysqli_query`). PHP just makes a string `$sql` for you, but obviously doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: Th only you should read about `mysql_query` that it's deprecated

Comment: holy god .... your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: Note also that storing derived data is a form of redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

pdo code example:

```
$pdo->prepare('UPDATE medical 
    SET pmts = pmts + :pmt
    WHERE dos = :dos AND patient = :patient')
->execute(array('pmt'=>$pmt,'dos'=>$dos,'patient'=>$patient));
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't enclosed your literal values with single quotes.

```
$sql="UPDATE medical 
SET pmts = pmts + $pmt
WHERE dos = '$dos' AND patient = '$patient'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just storing query in a string. Use functions to work with database (`PDO` or `mysqli`) to execute this query.

And you better should use prepared statements that build query yourself or you may get SQL Injections

Answer (score 0):

I saw a few errors in your code.  Check out this code:

```
$pmt = $_POST['pmt'];
$patient = $_POST['patient'];
$dos = $_POST['dos'];

$sql=("UPDATE medical 
SET pmts = pmts + '$pmt'
WHERE dos = '$dos' AND patient = '$patient'");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is refer to a column in MySQL.

```
$Qupdate=("UPDATE medical SET pmts = (pmts) + $pmt, out = (out) - $pmt WHERE dos = $dos AND patient = $patient");
```

It looks to me like you are only expecting numeric input, so I would also sterilise the $_POST data before using it.

```
$Qupdate=mysql_real_escape_string($Qupdate);
```

Also, because the variables being use are numbers, I don't think you need to enclose them in quotes.  but if you do (are not using numbers only).  Then you want to escape the quote mark ( \" )

```
$Qupdate=("UPDATE medical SET pmts = (pmts) + \"$pmt\", out = (out) - \"$pmt\" WHERE dos = \"$dos\" AND patient = \"$patient\"");
```